# Proteger archivo config.ini da error al usare para conexion mysqli

Tags: php

Basandome en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216019/is-it-safe-to-deny-access-to-ini-file-in-htaccess

encontre la siguiente forma de proteger el archivo config.ini para una conexion con mysqli:

```
;<?php
;die(); // For further security
;/*
    [database]
    driver=mysql
    host=localhost
    port=3306
    schema=base
    username=root
    password=
;*/
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   Warning: syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in __config.php on line 5

Si empleo comillas, basandome en el *http://php.net/parse_ini_file*

> (Values null, no and false results in "", yes and true results in "1".)

```
;<?php
    ;die(); // For further security
    ;/*
        [database]
        driver="mysql"
        host="localhost"
        port="3306"
        schema="base"
        username="root"
        password=""
    ;*/
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in __config.php on line 5

Cambiado a:

```
;<?php
;die(); // For further security
;/*[database]
host="localhost"
username="root"
password="" 
schema="base";*/
```

Ya no presenta error, pero creo que no se parsea bien

configurando base de datos:

```
$file ='__config.ini.php';

$config=parse_ini_file($file);

  $host = $config['database']['host'];
  echo $host;
  $user = $config['database']['user'];
  echo $user;
  $pass = $config['database']['pass'];
  echo $pass;
  $schema = $config['database']['schema'];
  echo $schema;
```

> Me da error, Undefined index: database para cada linea

Ultima modificación del ini:

```
;<?php
;die(); // For further security
;/*
[database]
driver="mysql"
host="localhost"
port="3306"
schema="base"
username="root"
password="" 
;*/
```

Conexion.php

```
<?php

$file ='__config.ini.php';

$config=parse_ini_file($file, true);

$host=$config['database']['host'];
$user=$config['database']['username'];
$pass=$config['database']['password'];
$schema=$config['database']['schema'];

class DBConnector {
    private static $instance ;
    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db){
      if (self::$instance){
        exit("Instance on DBConnection already exists.") ;
      }
    }

    public static function conectar(){
      if (!self::$instance){
        self::$instance = new DBConnector(a,b,c,d) ;
      }
      return $instance ;
    }
}

$mysqli = new DBConnector($host,$user,$pass,$schema);
?>
```

Linea para conectar:

```
require_once '__conexion.php';
$conexion = new DBConnector($host,$user,$pass,$schema);
```

Error:

> Call to undefined method DBConnector::prepare() linea 15

linea 15:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
```

Leyendo en php.net

consegui esto:

```
class conexion extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd) {
        parent::__construct($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd);

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Error de Conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}

$conexion = new conexion($host,$user,$pass,$schema);
```

Es mas seguro?

Comment: El código debe estar alineado a la izquierda, y no dejes espacios en blanco o sangría antes del `;`

Comment: Respecto al error `Call to undefined method DBConnector::prepare() linea 15`, tu clase no implementa dicho método, es posible que quisieras extender de alguna clase que sí lo haga y has olvidado indicarlo? A la pregunta de si es más seguro o no, dependerá de qué funciones uses para realizar la conexión en `DBConnector`, por lo general, las funciones mysqli_* son más seguras que mysql_*, cuyo uso está desaconsejado y obsoleto.

Comment: coloque la ultima clase que agregue y trabajo con

$sql / $stmt prepare / $stmt execute y asi voy haceindo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define el fichero .ini sin espacios a la izquierda:

```
;<?php
;die(); // For further security
;/*
[database]
driver="mysql"
host="localhost"
port="3306"
schema="base"
username="root"
password="" 
;*/
```

Usando la función `$config = parse_ini_file($file);` puedes acceder a los valores de esta manera:

```
<?php 
$config = parse_ini_file($file);
echo $config['driver'];
echo $config['host'];
```

Si quieres que se procesen las secciones, úsalo de esta manera `$config = parse_ini_file($file, true);` y podrás acceder a los valores mediante un array multidimensional:

```
<?php 
$config = parse_ini_file($file, true);
echo $config['database']['driver'];
echo $config['database']['host'];
```